# Log file configuration using Crate.IO database docker image

Tags: docker, logging, cratedb

The docker image is generating logs on console. Is there any configuration to setup rolling log files

Answer (score 1):

`docker run --it --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=3 crate` will give you logrotation of three archived logfiles and the maximum size of 50 megabytes.

For more details see the [docker logging overview](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/).